# Increment variable in another class

Tags: c#, class, variables

Is it even possible to increment a variable in another class? EXAMPLE:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public void Method1()//gets called
    {
        var c2=new Class2();
        c2.a++;
    }
}
public class Class2 
{
    public int a=1;
}
```

The code above only changes the value of a in c2 not in Class2.

After Method1 gets called I would want that "int a" in Class2 would get incremented by 1.
And the next time I would create a new instance of Class2 "a" would be 2.

Comment: You know `Class2` does not have a value `a`? Instances of `Class2` have this value, and you created one with `var c2=new Class2();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because it isn't `static`.

`static` variables apply to all instances of a class. If they aren't `static`.. they are local to each individual instance.

Changing your field declaration to this:

```
public class Class2  {
    public static int a = 1;
    //     ^^^^^^ this
}
```

Will work as you expect. However, you can't have an instance of a class to access `static` variables.. you must access it like this:

```
Class2.a++;
```

Comment: Moreover, you can't access the static member through an instance member and are required to use Class2.a++. As a sidenote, "a" should be a property and not a public data member.

Comment: Thanks @LordTakkera. I have rephrased.